# Edit Sketch options for digitizing polygons

Tags: qgis, editing

Trying my hand at building a methodology on QGIS as opposed to ESRI, and I'm having some issues with simple digitizing of irregular polygons.  The edit sketch graphic that appears when adding a new polygon feature is only transparent in the area where no coverage exists of previously added vertices.  The problem arises when trying to digitize a polygon that has internal angles.  It gets to a point in the digitizing that you can no longer see your base map to digitize from.  I have looked at QGIS digitizing options and how found nothing to adjust the transparency of the edit sketch polygon. so I might be able to see the underlying map as I digitize.  Screenshots below to illustrate my point.

Is there a way to combat this, other than to complete the polygon and then go in and modify individual nodes to position correctly?

[image: Boundary to be digitized]

[image: Overlap issue and inability to see inner corner]

[SOLVED] - By Jake below.  I missed the simple ability to modify the Alpha channel of the rubberband setting.

Comment: HaHa - That is exactly what I mean.  Doh! If it was a snake it would have bitten me.  Thanks Jake!

Comment: Hehe, glad it helps. I've converted the comment to an answer. Would you mind accepting it, so the question is marked as closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the transparency in "Settings / Options" "Digitizing" by changing the "Line Color" in the "Rubberband" section: Click on the coloured rectangle, and set the Alpha channel to something lower (100, say).